# Uploading custom jar to cx-server nexus

Tags: nexus, s4sdk, sap-cloud-sdk

So, I am trying to set up a CI/CD pipeline with the s4sdk. I successfully completed all the steps descriped in [this](https://blogs.sap.com/2017/09/20/continuous-integration-and-delivery/) blog. Everything seems to be running smoothly, however my build is failing with the following error message:

```
The following artifacts could not be resolved: com.sap.xs2.security:security-commons:jar:0.28.6, com.sap.xs2.security:java-container-security:jar:0.28.6, com.sap.xs2.security:java-container-security-api:jar:0.28.6, com.sap.security.nw.sso.linuxx86_64.opt:sapjwt.linuxx86_64:jar:1.1.19: Could not find artifact com.sap.xs2.security:security-commons:jar:0.28.6 in s4sdk-mirror (http://s4sdk-nexus:8081/repository/mvn-proxy/)
```

Now, this error messages makes sense to me, since I remember downloading these artifacts from the SAP download center and therefore those artifacts are not available on maven central.

I think this error can be resolved by manually uploading those artifacts to the nexus server, but I don't know how. According to the nexus documentation, there is a web ui reachable under http://< cx-server-ip>:8081, but it is somehow not responding.

I can confirm with `docker ps` that both the jenkins and nexus container are running and that the nexus container is listening on TCP 8081. I am also able to reach the jenkin's frontend to configure and run my pipeline.

What am I missing? Is uploading the missing artifacts to the nexus the right approach? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nexus container you see acts as a download cache and is by design not accessible from outside to prevent accidental changes to it. Also, its life-cycle is controlled by the `cx-server` script, so even if you installed packages there manually, they would be gone once you upgrade the Jenkins.

I think the best way to handle this would be to set up another Nexus instance where you install the required packages and configure the pipeline to use that as described [here](https://github.com/SAP/cloud-s4-sdk-pipeline/blob/master/doc/operations/operations-guide.md#configuring-the-cx-server) (`mvn_repository_url`). This nexus needs to be configured as a mirror for Maven central. We don't have specific docs on how to do that, but [this post](http://codeheaven.io/using-nexus-3-as-your-repository-part-1-maven-artifacts/) describes a similar setup.

In this set up, you might want to disable the download cache as it is redundant (`cache_enabled` to `false`).

I hope this helps.

Kind regards

Florian

Comment: Hey Florian, thank you for your answer. I fired up a second instance of nexus as descriped in your linked blog post and installed all required packages. Afterwards, I stopped the cx-server, removed the container, made the required changes to `server.cfg` (`mvn_repository_url` and `cache_enabled` to false) and restarted the cx-server. However my build is still failing with the same error message. The provided maven repositoty link doesn't seem to have any effect. Even if I set the url to a random string, Jenkins is still pulling from maven central. Am I missing something else?

Comment: My bad, the documentation for `mvn_repository_url` is misleading, it only applies to where the download cache gets its packets from, so it is the wrong setting in this case. Instead, you need to configure a `settings.xml` file for maven where you configure your nexus instance and set this as a project settings file, cf https://github.com/SAP/cloud-s4-sdk-pipeline/blob/master/configuration.md#mavenexecute

Answer (score 2):

The sidecar nexus acts as a read-only cache for maven and npm artifacts on the host (and agents) where cx server is running. By default it looks up artifacts from maven central and the default npm registry. In the current implementation, the cache will be completely deleted after stopping cx server, leading to a loss of all internal state.

If you want to use custom sources, you can set them in `server.cfg` via `mvn_repository_url` and `npm_registry_url`. This is documented in the operations guide, which you can find here: https://github.com/SAP/cloud-s4-sdk-pipeline/blob/master/doc/operations/operations-guide.md

In your case, you have to specify a maven repository which includes the dependencies in question.