# Jenkins Pipeline - Build Fail due to security JARS

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

Facing an issue in building the application in Jenkins Pipeline due to SAP security JARS. Attached screenshot as required. In Local, this is working fine as I have the JARS (Downloaded from SAP Portal)installed in the machine. Please let me know.
Note: One of the application JAR is missing from our application as in the screenshot which I know about it. The SAP security related JAR is what I am concerned about.

[image]

Thanks
Arun

Answer (score 2):

your question was already answered here [Uploading custom jar to cx-server nexus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55831055/uploading-custom-jar-to-cx-server-nexus)

Kind regards

Florian

Comment: Hi Florian, Thanks for the reply. Let me try that.